# When to implement WritableComparable and when to extend WritableComparator

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Just started exploring mapreduce,and i came across Writablecomparable interface which has compareTo() method and Writablecomparator which has compare() method, When we are writing our own Custom Writable classes, which should be used under what circumstances if we are implementing our own sorting mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer the link .very good explanation.

https://vangjee.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/implementing-rawcomparator-will-speed-up-your-hadoop-mapreduce-mr-jobs-2/